# Multiple message streaming over a socket

Tags: protocol-buffers

I am trying to talk to a C++ application as a server from a Java  web application over Socket. The server exposes a binary API in Protocol Buffer (using 2.6.1 on both sides and Java 8). On client I tried a socket connection pool to speed up performance. The first call was always successful and subsequent calls were timing out which was forcing Apache Commons Pool to destroy the socket connection. So I wrote a simple Java server and Java client to debug whats going on. The sources are below:

```
syntax = "proto2";

option java_package = "com.es.protos";
option java_outer_classname = "RequestProtos";
option optimize_for = SPEED;

message Request {
    oneof request {
        string ping = 3;
        string field1 = 4;
        string field2 = 5;
        string field3 = 6
    }
}

syntax = "proto2";

option java_package = "com.es.protos";
option java_outer_classname = "ResponseProtos";
option optimize_for = SPEED;

message Response {
    required string status = 1;
    oneof response {
        string ping = 3;
        string field1 = 4;
        string field2 = 5;
        string field3 = 6
    }
}

package com.es.socket;

import com.es.protos.RequestProtos.Request;
import com.es.protos.ResponseProtos.Response;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class TcpServer1 {

    final static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TcpServer1.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
        Socket socket = null;
        while (true) {
            try {
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                LOGGER.warn("Could not listen on port");
                System.exit(-1);
            }

            Thread thread = new Thread(new ServerConnection1(socket));
            thread.start();
        }
    }
}

class ServerConnection1 implements Runnable {

    static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ServerConnection.class.getName());

    private Socket socket = null;

    ServerConnection1(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            serveRequest(socket.getInputStream(), socket.getOutputStream());
            //socket.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            LOGGER.warn("Error", ex);
        }
    }

    public void serveRequest(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream) {
        try {
            read(inputStream);
            write(outputStream);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            LOGGER.warn("ERROR", ex);
        }
    }

    private void write(OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
        Response.Builder builder = Response.newBuilder();
        Response response = builder.setStatus("SUCCESS").setPing("PING").build();
        response.writeDelimitedTo(outputStream);
        LOGGER.info("Server sent {}", response.toString());
    }

    private void read(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        Request request = Request.parseDelimitedFrom(inputStream);
        LOGGER.info("Server received {}", request.toString());
    }

}

package com.es.socket;

import com.es.protos.RequestProtos.Request;
import com.es.protos.ResponseProtos.Response;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;

public class TcpClient1 {

    final static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TcpClient1.class.getName());

    private Socket openConnection(final String hostName, final int port) {
        Socket clientSocket = null;
        try {
            clientSocket = new Socket(hostName, port);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.warn("Exception occured while connecting to server", e);
        }
        return clientSocket;
    }

    private void closeConnection(Socket clientSocket) {
        try {
            LOGGER.info("Closing the connection");
            clientSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.warn("Exception occured while closing the connection", e);
        }
    }

    private void write(OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
        Request.Builder builder = Request.newBuilder();
        Request request = builder.setPing("PING").build();
        request.writeDelimitedTo(outputStream);
        LOGGER.info("Client sent {}", request.toString());
    }

    private void read(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        Response response = Response.parseDelimitedFrom(inputStream);
        LOGGER.info("Client received {}", response.toString());
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        TcpClient1 client = new TcpClient1();
        try {
            LOGGER.info("Start - One socket for all calls");
            Socket clientSocket = client.openConnection("localhost", Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
            OutputStream outputStream = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
            InputStream inputStream = clientSocket.getInputStream();
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                LOGGER.info("REQUEST {}", i);
                client.write(outputStream);
                client.read(inputStream);
            }
            client.closeConnection(clientSocket);
            LOGGER.info("End - One socket for all calls");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.warn("Exception occured", e);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

}
```

Here Request and Response are Protocol Buffer generated classes. The client sends one request and receives a response. It again sends another request reusing the socket. The server never receives this second request and the client never receives a response. How can I stream multiple messages over the same socket.

**Sample output below**

**Client Output**

```
18:09:10.733 [main] INFO  c.d.e.socket.TcpClient1 - Start --> One socket for all calls
18:09:10.733 [main] INFO  c.d.e.socket.TcpClient1 - REQUEST 0
18:09:10.734 [main] INFO  c.d.e.socket.TcpClient1 - Client sent ping: "PING"
18:09:10.734 [main] INFO  c.d.e.socket.TcpClient1 - Client received status: "SUCCESS"
ping: "PING"
18:09:10.734 [main] INFO  c.d.e.socket.TcpClient1 - REQUEST 1
18:09:10.735 [main] INFO  c.d.e.socket.TcpClient1 - Client sent ping: "PING"
```

**Server Output**

```
18:09:10.734 [Thread-0] INFO  c.d.e.socket.ServerConnection - Server received ping: "PING"
18:09:10.734 [Thread-0] INFO  c.d.e.socket.ServerConnection - Server sent status: "SUCCESS"
ping: "PING"
```

Thanks,
AK

Comment: Any idea whats happening here. Once a socket has been used it is getting stuck on subsequent requests.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue and its resolved. Its a problem in the ServerConnection1 class. This thread's run method is designed to handle just one request/response. Putting a while loop in the run method can handle as many request/response as you wish.